# Undefined function crypto:start/0

Tags: macos, erlang

I get the following error when trying to call `crypto:start/0`:

> ** exception error: undefined function crypto:start/0

See below. I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5.

```
kartik:ejabberd-master Kartik$ erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
1> crypto:start().
** exception error: undefined function crypto:start/0
2> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Jun-2015::17:15:53 ===

Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:

"load, Library load-call unsuccessful."

OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Jun-2015::17:15:53 ===

The on_load function for module crypto returned {error,                                                 {load,"Library load-call unsuccessful."}}
```

Comment: As the error message indicates, the `crypto` facility relies on OpenSSL under the covers. If OpenSSL isn't installed, or is installed somewhere unknown to the Erlang runtime, `crypto` won't work.

Comment: I followed instructions given at http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/&ei=_F7K3Upo&lc=en-IN&geid=2&s=1&m=137&ts=1435494015&sig=AG8Ucuk6v2BzYQ9uGRyDyOW84t7U_U5FpQ . used "brew install Erlang". When I type " which openssl" in terminal it shows version 0.9. Can this be due to some version or port mismatch. I am pretty new to this work. Really appreciate your quick response

Comment: Do you have a `/usr/lib/libcrypto` dynamic library? Run `ls /usr/lib/libcrypto*` to find out. Perhaps you can then use `brew info Erlang` to determine where erlang is installed, run a `find` command to locate `crypto.so` under that install area, then run `otool -L <path>/crypto.so` (where `<path>` is the path determined from the `find` command) to see which `libcrypto` the `crypto.so` library depends on. Maybe its dependency doesn't match what the `ls` command shows.

Comment: Hi Steve, 
please find answers to command I executed as per your direction below. 

kartik:ejabberd-master Kartik$ ls /usr/lib/libcrypto*
/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib

kartik:ejabberd-master Kartik$ brew info Erlang
Erlang: stable 17.5, HEAD
/usr/local/Cellar/Erlang/17.5 (7398 files, 282M)

///// I could not find crypto.so in above path

kartik:17.5 Kartik$ find . | grep -i crypto.so

Comment: however, i found crypto.so somewhere else. i ran coomand given by you.       kartik:17.5 Kartik$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.5/priv/lib/crypto.so 
/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.5/priv/lib/crypto.so:
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)          let me know if you want me to run anything else.

Comment: The missing `crypto.so` is almost certainly the problem. I guess the `brew` version was built without it. I recommend downloading and installing Erlang 17.5 from [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp) instead.

Comment: thanks steve for very quick response. do I need to un-intstall existing erlang setup? if yes, please guide me thru commands or link to uninstall

Comment: also erlang 17.5 is for macos 10.10 do I need to install lower version of erlang(like 17.1) for 10.7.5?

Comment: I think you can just `brew uninstall Erlang` and then install the other package.

Comment: And as for versions, Erlang 17.5 can be built and run on your version of OS X. Since you're running 10.7.5, you might consider downloading the Erlang 17.5 sources and building it yourself, which is pretty easy: just `configure`, `make`, `make install`.

Comment: thanks Steve for all your help. Key was to download source from erlang site and compile, install it in mac os. I manage to resolve error. Really great to have contributors like you on stackoverflow!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear you got it working.